# Convert time to UTC from desire timezone

Tags: node.js, reactjs, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have to convert time to UTC time from various time zone as per requirements.

I'm using momnet with node, and I have coded as below:

```
const inputTime = "10:00";
const timezone = "Europe/Budapest";
const localTime = moment.tz(inputTime, timezone).utc().format("HH:mm");
console.log(localTime);
```

I'm getting **Invalid date** as o/p.
Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to supply the format of the input string you are parsing.

```js
const inputTime = "10:00";
const timezone = "Europe/Budapest";
const localTime = moment.tz(inputTime, "HH:mm", timezone).utc().format("HH:mm");
console.log(localTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.38/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind that the input is representing the time on the current date only.  The conversion may return a different value depending on when you run it.

Comment: Also, if this is a new project, please choose a different library than Moment.  See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/